# Why do I need to install node.js and git to learn AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am presently reading [Manning's AngularJS in Action by Lukas Ruebbelke](http://www.manning.com/ruebbelke/CH1_sample.pdf)

The introductory part suggests,

Because you’re pulling files from a `CDN`, you’ll need to run
Angello Lite(the application name) from a web server. There are a few ways to do this, but one of the easiest ways is to use the `npm package serve`.
The steps for installing Angello Lite are as follows:

```
■    Install Node.js. You can find all of the information to do that at http://
     nodejs.org/.
■    Install the serve package by running npm install -g serve from the command
     line.
■    Download Angello Lite from GitHub, using the URL given above, and place it
     on your local machine in a directory named angello-lite.
■    Navigate to the angello-lite directory from the command line and run serve.
■    Go to http://localhost:3000 in your browser to see the application.
```

Does learning `Angular JS` require previous exposure to `node` and `git`?

If I have Apache Tomcat already configured on my local m/c, what is the procedure to start with it?

Furthermore, just to keep in sync with the author, I installed `git` and then cloned a `dir` onto my local m/c from `github`.

Then i install `node.js` and  `Install the serve package by running`npm install -g serve`from the command line.`

Unfortunately when i navigate to the angello-lite directory from the command line and run serve, it shows me

[image]
where angello-lite is the repository where the application resides?

Any suggestions on how to configure successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have no idea regarding node.js and git. Do i really need to learn
>   these to begin with AngularJS then.

No, that's not a requirement. You don't even need a web server. You can have your static HTML files locally or use some online service like [`plnkr`](http://plnkr.co/). Obviously if you need to work with dynamic data then you will need a web server. At some point you might want to start making AJAX calls in order to fetch some dynamic data from your server backend.

> If I have Apache Tomcat already configured on my local m/c, what is
>   the procedure to start with it?

Just add an HTML page to the root of your website, open your favorite browser and invoke this page.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need those tools to learn Angular - you can download latest package from the AngularJS website (both for development and for production).

Node.js and Git may be necessary to pull and build packages from the NPM, run tasks and many more great features, but just to learn Angular all you need is its code.